# Is there any way to call Bing-ads api through a pipeline and load the data into Bigquery through Google Data Fusion?

Tags: rest, google-bigquery, bing-ads-api, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I'm creating a pipeline in Google Data Fusion that allows me to export my bing-ads data into Bigquery using my bing-ads developer token. I couldn't find any data sources that should be added to my pipeline in data fusion. Is fetching data from API calls even supported on Google Data Fusion and if it is, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP based sources for Cloud Data Fusion are currently in development and will be released by Q3. Could you elaborate on your use case a little more, so we can make sure that your requirements will be covered by those plugins? For example, are you looking to build a batch or real-time pipeline?

In the meantime, you have the following two, more immediate options/workarounds:

1. If you are ok with storing the data in a staging area in GCS before loading it into BigQuery, you can use the HTTPToHDFS plugin that is available in the Hub. Use a path that starts with gs:///path/to/file
2. Alternatively, we also welcome contributions, so you can also build the plugin using the Cloud Data Fusion APIs. We are happy to guide you, and can point you to documentation and samples.

Comment: I'm looking more at scheduled batch jobs here. I've noticed there is a http-poller data source in streaming-pipelines for enterprise version but I couldn't run anything using it. Since I would get xml data through bing-ads api, I tried running the XML-parser pipeline available from the Hub. The run failed with an error : "java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of io.cdap.plugin.common.http.HTTPPollConfig to field io.cdap.plugin.spark.HTTPPollerSource.conf of type io.cdap.plugin.common.http.HTTPPollConfig in instance of io.cdap.plugin.spark.HTTPPollerSource"

Comment: Looks like Cloud data-fusion is still under development and currently, there is no support for http calls. I got the http-poller data source working for making http calls in CDAP though. Still, I can't pull off the Bing-ads api request through CDAP pipelines as it seems that the request should go through oauth process which is currently not possible in CDAP. Thanks.